# Grouping problem in figure vertical alignment of text

Tags: wrapfigure, grouping

I had the same problem as in [LINK](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365753/). The question is about using \endgroup somewhere. If I use the following code

```
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=1in,top=1.2in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setlength\intextsep{0pt}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\draw[step=1cm,very thin] (0,0) grid (13,8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\noindent \lipsum[1]
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

it would look like this picture
[image: Test1]

However, if I add an empty line after `\lipsum[1]`

```
(... like above)
\noindent \lipsum[1]

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

it would look like this picture
[image: Test2]

Why is there a difference in the code? If I replace this empty line with `\\`, `\newline` or even `\hfill \break`, none changes. What does this ''empty line'' in grouping mean? Is there other way to fill this empty line to make the code work as in the second picture?

Comment: You should not use `wrapfig` in a group or if you do, as you show, make sure the paragraph ends before the group ends.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The only reason I used group is ````\setlength\intextsep{0pt}```` to move the figure a little bit up, only for this figure without affecting other future figures. I followed similar method in [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45030/50564) about grouping

Comment: just us a vspace, wrapfig says   _If you put a wrapfigure in a parbox or a minipage, or any other type  of grouping, the text wrapping should end before the group does._  So if you have the group you must end the paragraph with blank line before endgroup, and even then it may not work
`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, I don't understand what you meant by vspace. Where should I write it? If I remove begingroup and endgroup, and move the ````\setlength\intextsep{0pt}```` in the premable, everything works as I wanted. But it would mean that all other figures would be affected by this code as well

Comment: `begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0pt}\vspace{-10pt}\begin{tik...`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried your code, and it worked. But if I add some text (lipsum) before this wrap figure, it wouldn't work anymore